# TextView.append slowed down while appending

Tags: android

I'm trying to generate a full screen `TextView` that auto-appends a random binary number to it. I wrote this code:

```
Button button;
TextView textView;
Random rand;

private static final char[] ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING = "01".toCharArray();

public PlaceholderFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,false);

    rand = new Random();
    textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i=0; i<1000; i++){
textView.append(String.valueOf(ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING[rand.nextInt(ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING.length)]));
            }
        }
    });

    button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new CountDownTimer(5000, 1) {

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

 textView.append(String.valueOf(ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING[rand.nextInt(ALPHA_NUMERIC_STRING.length)]));

                 final int scrollAmount = textView.getLayout().getLineTop(textView.getLineCount()) - textView.getHeight();
                // if there is no need to scroll, scrollAmount will be <=0
                if (scrollAmount > 0)
                    textView.scrollTo(0, scrollAmount);
                else
                    textView.scrollTo(0, 0);
             }

             public void onFinish() {
             textView.append("done!");
             }
          }.start();
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

This code works fine. It's writing a random string into my `textView`. The problem comes when my textView becomes really big. When it has a lot of chars, when I add a new char and try to append it, I  notice the add and repaint process is really slow.

Does anybody know why is this being slowed down? How can I make it work fast?

PS: this code is located inside a `Fragment`.

Comment: Its better to use `StringBuilder` and set it to `TextView`.

Comment: Run layoutopt tool to check the execution times. Also with huge text blocks the the view update will always take some time since even if you append to the textview, everything is redrawn anyway. The benefit of using append over settext is that you dont overwrite the text buffer, but the view is invalidated "as a whole" anyway

Answer (score 0):

Use **TextView** inside a **ScrollView** to display messages with any no.of lines.

I think this is good for your requirement. Try it once.

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100px"
    android:textColor="#f00"
    android:textSize="25px"
    android:typeface="serif"
    android:textStyle="italic"/>
```

if you want to change dynamically whenever you want use as below:

```
TextView textarea = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);  // tv is id in XML file for TextView
textarea.setTextSize(20);
```